# ProxyPass apache на два хоста или как это работает?

Tags: linux, apache, http-status-code-404, proxypass

Всем добрейшего времени суток.
Проведу пример, пробовал делать

```
    ServerName service.test.com

    SSLProxyEngine on

  <Proxy "balancer://service">
    BalancerMember https://service1.ng.com
    BalancerMember https://service2.ng.com
  </Proxy>

    ProxyPass "/" "balancer://service/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer://service/"
```

В /etc/hosts прописал 2 записи, для BalanceMember. Что на этих виртуалках, не в курсе, не посмотреть, черный ящик. Все запросы улетают в 404 not found. НО...

Если я отредактирую /etc/hosts и следом подправлю конфигу

```
    ServerName service.test.com

    SSLProxyEngine on

  <Proxy "balancer://service">
    BalancerMember https://service.ng.com
    BalancerMember https://service2.ng.com
  </Proxy>

    ProxyPass "/" "balancer://service/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer://service/"
```

Один запрос из 2 будет отдавать 200 ОК.
Понимаете, да? А я вот не могу понять.
Что передаёт прокся на один из балансеров, что всё работает. Ну или после балансера, не знаю.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать, желательно не просто "Загугли", а более точечную отсылку.
Заранее благодарю за ответ и всем хорошего дня :)